# NSString format question

Tags: objective-c, coding-style

Here are two ways to make a `NSString`.

```
NSString *sBody = [NSString stringWithString:@"Hello"]
```

versus

```
NSString *sBody = @"Hello"
```

Most of the time, I see it the first way.  But is it also "clean" to use the second, or is it better to not use it?

Thanks and have a nice day!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are equivalent.  It's less code to use the literal (the second example), so I would just use that.

Answer (score 2):

It's the same, the first way you're helping the compiler but it already does a great job optimizing string vars.

Comment: How does the first example help the compiler?

Comment: If it's a string, the NSString class must do all the work. So, if you use the second example, the compiler will convert that to use the same way of the first example.

Comment: Er, no. If you use `@"Hello"` then the compiler dynamically creates a special form of NSString and builds it directly into the compiled binary file's data segment. It also takes the raw C-string data (in UTF-8 format) and places that into the binary file's text segment. The built-in NSString's data ptr points to the built-in C string. The compiler doesn't convert it to a method invocation, it just builds in the data and references it directly (i.e. a single `ldw` or `mov` instruction).